# Set focus back to Excel after loading modeless userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm which displays additional information based on the selection made on the worksheet.

The procedure which calls the Userform is in the worksheet module and the trigger is the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. The form is modeless so that the user can select a different cell on the worksheet. The form with the data is shown.

The problem is that the Userform takes focus away from the Excel application so that the arrow keys do not function. And since the trigger is a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, it always takes focus after a selection change.

How do I set the focus back from the Userform or prevent the Userform from taking focus in the first place?

I've looked at the Application properties to regain focus and the Userform properties to remove focus from the Userform but can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe `AppActivate Application.Caption`

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, this works perfectly,.Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would typically use:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

Comment: This does its job in focusing back on the application window itself ... but it doesn't focus on the actual cell/range where I want the focus to be. I use `ActiveCell.Activate` instead, and this returns the focus back to the previous selection in the current worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Not real solution but a possible workaround that mimic show/hide without stealing focus more than once.

The idea is to Show the Modeless Userform and move it off screen when the workbook is opened (before the user can do anything with it).

Then when that `Worksheet_SelectionChange` with specific requirements met, move the Userform into viewable screen (`UserForm1.ShowInScreen(LeftLocation)`), otherwise move it off screen (`UserForm1.GoOffScreen`).

Sample below assumes **Userform1 is Disabled** with just a textbox here to display address of selected cell, and only "show" userform when selection is a single cell at Column B of Sheet1.

It may also work by changing the Userform Height and Width to zero to mimic hide (not tested).

**<kbd>ThisWorkbook</kbd>**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With UserForm1
        .Show
        .GoOffScreen
    End With
End Sub
```

**<kbd>Sheet1</kbd>** (where you want to userform to react)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            With UserForm1
                If Not .Visible Then .Show
                .ShowInScreen Application.Left + Target.Width + Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
                .UpdateTextbox Target.Address(0, 0)
            End With
        Else
            UserForm1.GoOffScreen
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally the **<kbd>Userform1</kbd>**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTextbox(ByVal Text As String)
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Text
End Sub

Sub GoOffScreen()
    ' Assuming no screen above this: move above the screen 3 times the userform height
    With Me
        .Top = -3 * .Height
    End With
End Sub

Sub ShowInScreen(ByVal LeftLocation As Double)
    With Me
        .Top = Application.Top + 200
        .Left = LeftLocation
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I like this workaround and I may use it in the future but @Tim Williams comment did the trick and set focus back to the workbook.

Comment: Interesting, Tim's method didn't work on my excel 2010 hence my workaround. Maybe something wrong with my computer.

Comment: I'm using the Ofice 365 Excel 2016 so that might be the key.